# Unable to boot after installing grub for new Arch Linux Install on Acer S7

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, acer, raid0

I have followed the instructions on the [Arch Linux beginner's guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/beginners%27_guide) to do a dual boot on an Acer S7-392. I only did not do the `initramfs` part and I did not create the partitions at the install since I used another tool to create the partitions before the install.

Also I did not do any part to install a RAID0 as the USB stick found  the RAID0 after booting without me having to do anything.

Also I made the following choices:

- `/dev/mp126p5` is my `/`
- `/dev/mp126p6` is my `/boot`
- `/dev/mp126p7` is my `swap`

However after installing Grub, I am unable to boot Linux. I managed to add an entry for Windows and boot it successfully.
`blkid` returns the following:

```
/dev/sda: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/sdb: TYPE="isw_raid_member"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="ARCH_201503" UUID="1E0A-194C" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="c3072e18-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: UUID="5aecb61b-2567-403a-a752-050e4d164111" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/loop2: UUID="5aecb61b-2567-403a-a752-050e4d164111" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/arch_airootfs: UUID="5aecb61b-2567-403a-a752-050e4d164111" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/md126p1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="70583CED583CB3A6" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="498d4ed4-3188-4daa-8059-824c94fd919a"
/dev/md126p2: LABEL="ESP" UUID="443E-CEA7" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="5590eefc-4879-4ad8-bdbb-83addea5df0c"
/dev/md126p4: LABEL="Windows" UUID="8C48153E4815290A" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="ad25c7d6-ab88-4e42-be00-48fb3695771c"
/dev/md126p5: LABEL="ARCH" UUID="a5e3b60e-8359-8c5e-24d5-b31dcdb7c56c" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="1dc85605-e2b2-4887-9f91-3b8e08a9b23d"
/dev/md126p6: UUID="C65D-DD84" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="1b97aac7-91ea-490f-c87b-de63a37540a1"
/dev/md126p7: UUID="402ac0b6-7a85-40ff-8757-6e5aa62a7d46" TYPE="swap" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="591680a4-bda3-452b-75cc-54084b005b34"
/dev/md126p8: LABEL="Push Button Reset" UUID="E45E43485E43132A" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="03da0cd7-674e-494a-9b11-94bea46585ea"
/dev/md126: PTUUID="db649bd9-6051-46ac-8a57-6506552ae288" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/md126p3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="18c44381-ef76-4f4b-8b26-f92980cfe007"
```

My /boot/grub/grub.cfg file can be found at this [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/pYqPqtRf). I have added one entry to boot Windows and this works: I can boot Windows successfully.

I used the following script to install grub:

```
##!/bin/bash
grub-mkconfig > /boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=grub_uefi --boot-directory=/boot --recheck --debug
```

On startup, after selecting the Arch partition in grub, I see the following on the screen:

```
[ xxxxxxxxxx] Ignoring BGRT: Invalid status 0 (expected 1)
starting version 218
ERROR: device 'UUID=a5e3b60e-8359-8c5e-24d5-b31dcdb7c56c' not found. Skipping fsck.
ERROR: Unable to find root device 'UUID=a5e3b60e-8359-8c5e-24d5-b31dcdb7c56c' .
You are being dropped to a recovery shell
    Type 'exit' to try and continue booting
sh: can't access tty: job control turned off
[rootfs /]#
```

This is strange because, when I booted on the usb stick, I installed `/` in `/dev/md126p5` and the UUID looks correct (if it is not it is because I typed by hand the error message after booting):

The contents of `/etc/fstab` are:

```
# 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
# /dev/md126p5 LABEL=ARCH

# /dev/md126p5 LABEL=ARCH
UUID=a5e3b60e-8359-8c5e-24d5-b31dcdb7c56c   /           ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 1

# /dev/md126p6
UUID=C65D-DD84          /boot       vfat        rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro    0 2

# /dev/md126p4 LABEL=Windows
UUID=8C48153E4815290A   /win8       ntfs        rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096  0 0

# /dev/md126p2 LABEL=ESP
UUID=443E-CEA7          /winboot    vfat        rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro    0 2

# /dev/md126p7
UUID=402ac0b6-7a85-40ff-8757-6e5aa62a7d46   none        swap        defaults    0 0
```

I am a bit struggling on this one, is it because the Acer S7 comes with a RAID 0 by default ? I have never installed Linux on a RAID 0, I assumed that because the USB stick can find the RAID 0 I would not have to do anything special to make it work.

Comment: I managed to solve this, I will post what I did whenever I can get some time to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I put a [larger article](http://nguyen.ly/2015/03/11/installing-arch-linux-in-a-dual-boot-with-uefi-on-an-ultrabook-acer-s7-392/) on [my blog](http://nguyen.ly) but will recap below how I solved this issue should my website go down.

It seems that the Acer-S7 comes with a RAID0 out of the box, after booting on the USB install disk, you will see devices such as `/dev/md126`.

After installing the bare OS, you need to make sure that you boot with an initramfs which can recognise this RAID.

For me the solution was to dd the following lines in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`:

```
MODULES="ext4 dm_mod raid0"
...
HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block mdadm_udev filesystems keyboard fsck shutdown"
```

Then install the initramfs and updating grub with the following commands:

```
mkinitcpio -p linux
grub-mkconfig &gt; /boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=grub_uefi --boot-directory=/boot --recheck
```